# What is range/v3/functional/comparisons.hpp for?

Tags: c++, templates, predicate, range-v3

What is [this header for](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/functional/comparisons.hpp)?

It defines, just to give an example, `equal_to`:

```cpp
namespace ranges
{
    /// \addtogroup group-functional
    /// @{
    struct equal_to
    {
        template(typename T, typename U)(
            /// \pre
            requires equality_comparable_with<T, U>)
        constexpr bool operator()(T && t, U && u) const
        {
            return (T &&) t == (U &&) u;
        }
        using is_transparent = void;
    };

    // ... and the others, such as !=, <, <=, ...
}
```

But what is the advantage of `ranges::equal_to` over `std::equal_to`? Only saving `<>` when instantiating an object of it's class, i.e. writing `ranges::equal_to{}` instead of `std::equal_to<>{}`?

Comment: I think this is compatibility related. Range v3 first was written using C++14 (AFAIR). Now since C++20 is used (I see feature `requires`), this remained to not break existing code which used this struct before C++20 was introduced to a code base.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `<>` with std::equal_to either anymore. This is a language version thing, and not a library thing.

Comment: @BoP, why not a library thing? Isn't it simply that they added a `void` specialization for the template class? (I'm referring to `template< class T = void > struct equal_to;` at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to).)

Comment: @Enlico omitting the empty `<>` is a language feature of C++17

Comment: It has the same advantages over `std::equal_to` that `std::ranges::equal_to` has. I suppose a better question would have been why C++20 added `std::ranges::equal_to`, which would have been easily researched

Answer (score 1):

> What is the advantage of `ranges::equal_to` over `std::equal_to`? Only saving `<>` when instantiating an object of its class, i.e. writing `ranges::equal_to{}` instead of `std::equal_to<>{}`?

That is not true, since omitting empty `<>` has been allowed since C++17.

---

> What is `range/[...]/comparisons.hpp` for?

The main differences between the `ranges::` comparison function objects and the base versions is that the `ranges` versions are much more constrained, due to the requirement `equality_comparable_with<T, U>`. <sub>The same difference also applies between and `std::` version and C++20 `std::ranges::` version.</sub>

---

For `std::equal_to{}(a, b)` to be valid code, all you need is `a == b` being valid code.

However, for `ranges::equal_to{}(a, b)` to be valid code, `a` and `b` must satisfy the [`equality_comparable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable) requirement. Which means not only `a == b` need to be valid, all equality checks between `a` and `b` must also be valid code(includes self comparison), which would include:

```cpp
a == a;
a != a;
b == b;
b != b;
a == b;
a != b;
b == a;
b != a;
```

In the same time, there must also be a common type `C` between `a` and `b`, where both `c == c` and `c != c` are valid code.

---

Similar behaviors can be observed on other `ranges::` comparison function objects, such as `ranges::not_equal_to` and `ranges::less`.